# Capybara Action integer (id) vs. string (name) confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

Part of my test requires selecting a university from this form field:

```
<div class="js-dependent-fields" data-select-id="user_role" data-option-value="staff">
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :university %>
    <%= form.select :university_id, options_for_select(University.all.map{ |uni| [uni.name, uni.id] }), {prompt: 'Select Your University'}, { class: "form-control" } %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the actual html:

```
<div class="js-dependent-fields" data-select-id="user_role" data-option-value="staff">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="user_university">University</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="user[university_id]" id="user_university_id"><option value="">Select Your University</option>
<option value="1">Harvard</option></select>
  </div>
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
  test_signup_valid_user                                         ERROR (0.05s)
Capybara::ElementNotFound:         Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find visible option "Harvard University"
            test/integration/boarding_flow_test.rb:63:in `block in <class:BoardingFlowTest>'
```

When the form is submitted, this is an example of what it passes as part of the parameters

```
"university_id"=>"4"
```

In the below test I want to select a university, and I've tried every combination I can think of like:

```
page.select "3", from: "university_id"
page.select "Harvard University", from: "University"
```

but I can't seem to get it to work. What is the proper way to do this? Thanks!

```
test 'signup valid user' do
    visit sign_up_path

    fill_in "First name", with: "John"
    fill_in "Last name", with: "Doe"
    fill_in "Email", with: "approved@doe.com"
    fill_in "Password", with: "foobar"
    page.select "Staff", from: "Role"
    page.select "3", from: "university_id"

    click_on "Signup"

    assert_equal sign_in_path, current_path
    assert page.has_content?("confirm your email")
  end
```

**Here is users/new.html.erb**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-4 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-4">
    <div class="login-panel panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Signup</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <%= form_for @user do |form| %>
          <fieldset>
            <%= render partial: '/users/form', object: form %>

            <%= form.submit t(".submit"), class: "btn btn-md btn-success btn-block" %>
            <hr>
            <h5 class="text-center">Already have an account?</h5>
            <%= link_to t(".login"), sign_in_path, class: "btn btn-md btn-info btn-block" %>
          </fieldset>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Here's the form partial**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= form.label :first_name %>
  <%= form.text_field :first_name, class: "form-control" %>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <%= form.label :last_name %>
  <%= form.text_field :last_name, class: "form-control" %>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <%= form.label :email %>
  <%= form.text_field :email, type: 'email', class: "form-control" %>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <%= form.label :password %>
  <%= form.password_field :password, class: "form-control" %>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <%= form.label :role %>
  <%= form.select :role, options_for_select(User.roles.keys.map{ |role| [User.human_attribute_name("role.#{role}"), role] }), {}, { class: "form-control" } %>
</div>

<div class="js-dependent-fields" data-select-id="user_role" data-option-value="staff">
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :university %>
    <%= form.select :university_id, options_for_select(University.all.map{ |uni| [uni.name, uni.id] }), {prompt: 'Select Your University'}, { class: "form-control" } %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: FYI - This isn't your current issue, but you should be using the assertions provided by Capybara rather than `assert_equal` and `assert`.  The Capybara provided assertions have waiting/retrying behavior to prevent flaky tests.   `assert_current_path(sign_in_path)` instead of your `assert_equal ...` and `assert_content("confirm your email")` instead of your `assert page.has_content?(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `page.select` - the main parameter is matched using the 'option' selector type - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/selector.rb#L413 - and the `:from` option is matched using the 'select' selector type - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/selector.rb#L358.  This means the `:from` option will match the name, id, placeholder or associated label text of an HTML `<select>` element, and the main parameter will match the text of the selectable option.  You don't show the actual HTML of the page or the details of the `form` object you're calling 'form.select' on - but if it's a user object it could be something like

```
page.select("Harvard", from: 'user_university_id') # assuming the id of the actual select is 'user_university_id'
```

If there is only one select on the page with an option of "Harvard University", you could also just do

```
page.select "Harvard"
```

The reasons your attempts didn't work is because -

```
# Doesn't work because "3" isn't the readable text of the option and
# 'university_id' is not the id of the select element
page.select "3", from: "university_id"

# Doesn't work because "University" is not the label text associated
# with the select.  This is because your partials label line would need to be
#   form.label :university_id, "University"
# to link the label with the university_id select element.  Additionally 
# "Harvard University" isn't actually the text shown in your HTML - it's just "Harvard"
page.select "Harvard University", from: "University"
```

This all assumes the visible element on the page is actually a `<select>` element and not a JS driven widget (which the class of `js-dependent-fields` on the wrapping div would tend to indicate it might be).  If the visible elements(s) is/are a JS widget then this all goes out the window since `page.select` only works with HTML `<select>` elements and you will need to show the actual HTML for the visible select widget on your page.

Comment: Thanks Thomas - the University dropdown is hidden unless staff is selected as the role.

Comment: @mike9182 If the code in my answer doesn't select what you want -- show the actual HTML from that section of the page (not the erb) so that we can see what the actual id assigned to the element is -- you can get the whole pages html by doing something like `puts page.html` before trying to select.  Also add the exact error you are getting to your question.

Comment: Thanks Thomas for the help - I just added the relevant HTML to the question and the exact error I get using your code.

Comment: @mike9182 From the HTML, the text of the option is "Harvard" not "Harvard University" - updated my answer to match the HTML

Comment: that is so strange - in the database it's "Harvard University". Thanks!